# R code for replacing the values of Matrix

Tags: r, matlab

[image: Snapshot of MATLAB Output]

Hey everyone, I have a large Matrix X with the dimensions (654x7095). I wanted to subset this matrix and replace the values of this subsetted matrix of X with another matrix which I have created. The R-code is as follows -

```
install.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("base")
library(Matrix)
library(base)
T = 215
n = 3
k = 33
X = matrix(0,T*n,T*k)
IN = diag(n)
K1 = Matrix(0, n*n, n*(n-1)/2, sparse = TRUE)
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
  K1[(2+(i-1)*(n+1)):(i*n), (1+(i-1)*(n-i/2)):(i*(n-i)*(i+1)/2)] <- diag(n-i)
}
yin = matrix(rnorm(645), ncol = 3)
Xu = matrix(rnorm(2150), ncol = 10)
#Till yet I have defined the variables and matrices which will be used in subsetting.
```

Above codes are perfectly fine, however, the code below is showing error -

```
#Loop for X subsetting
for(i in 1:T){
  X[(((i-1)*n)+1):(i*n), (((i-1)*k)+1):(i*k)] <- cbind( (t(kronecker(yin[i,],IN))%*%K1) , (t(kronecker(Xu[i,],IN))))
}
# in this Kronecker() finds the Kronecker tensor product of two Matrix A and B. This function can be used with the help of "base" library.
```

When I am running this above code, the error which is showing is -

```
Error in X[(((i - 1) * n) + 1):(i * n), ] <- cbind((t(kronecker(yin[i,  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

However, when I am running this same command in MATLAB it is working perfectly fine. MATLAB CODE -

```
X = zeros(T*n,T*k);
for i = 1:T
  X((i-1)*n+1:i*n,(i-1)*k+1:i*k) = [kron(yin(i,:),IN)*K1, kron(Xu(i,:),IN)];
end
```

The output which MATLAB is giving is that it fills up the values in number of rows and columns which is defined in the Loop for subsetting the X. I have attached the snapshot of the desired output which MATLAB is giving. However, error is showing in R for the same.

Can someone enlighten me as where I am going wrong with the R code?

I appreciate the help, Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how the class 'dgeMatrix' is handled. Try

```
for (i in 1:T) {
    X[(((i-1)*n)+1):(i*n), (((i-1)*k)+1):(i*k)] <- as.matrix(cbind((t(kronecker(yin[i,],IN))%*%K1) , (t(kronecker(Xu[i,],IN)))))
}
```